# ActionBarSherlock: ViewPagerTutorial: tutorial crashes when orientation is changed

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I installed the ViewPagerTutorial from here:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/

and it immediately crashes as soon as you change the orientation.

### UPDATE:  logcat

```
shell@android:/ $ logcat                                                       
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/ActivityManager(  379): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial/.MainActivity} from pid 8321
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/dalvikvm(17204): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  379): Start proc com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial for activity com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial/.MainActivity: pid=17204 uid=10118 gids={50118, 1028}
D/dalvikvm(  127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 1% free 8629K/8700K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 34ms
D/dalvikvm(  127): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 1% free 8629K/8700K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 30ms
I/ActivityManager(  379): No longer want com.vzw.apnservice (pid 16919): empty for 1801s
D/dalvikvm(  127): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 1% free 8629K/8700K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 25ms
W/ActivityManager(  379): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.vzw.apnservice/.VZWAPNService in 5000ms
D/libEGL  (17204): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (17204): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (17204): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/OpenGLRenderer(17204): Enabling debug mode 0
I/ActivityManager(  379): Displayed com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial/.MainActivity: +611ms
I/ActivityManager(  379): Config changes=1480 {1.0 311mcc480mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w598dp h335dp 320dpi nrml land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.81}
I/InputReader(  379): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  379): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', size 720x1280, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
D/AndroidRuntime(17204): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(17204): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412f5930)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17204): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(17204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  379):   Force finishing activity com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial/.MainActivity
D/dalvikvm(17204): GC_CONCURRENT freed 190K, 3% free 8833K/9052K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 33ms   
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ahmad, I have a logcat but how do I post it here?  The markdown is crazy.

Comment: Ahmad, why you change the status to off-topic?  I tried attempting to post a logcat but the markdown would always cut it off very short to about 15 lines.  So I posted it without markdown and Howlin was able to modify it somehow to work.  Maybe my browser is the problem?  Anyway, what specifically is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

```
In AndroidManifest.xml

In <activity
add:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```